# Entity Framework early loading not loading related entities for all rows

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am having a strange behavior in Entity Framework 5

I use the following code to load the entity "Question" (along with its answers and results given by users) and then I test if all the questions have the number of answers they should (4 answers for round 1 and round 2 questions and 1 answer for round 3 question):

```
var round1Questions = Entities.Questions.Where(q => q.Round == 1)
                          .OrderBy(r => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(numOfQuestions).ToList();
var round2Questions = Entities.Questions.Where(q => q.Round == 2)
                          .OrderBy(r => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(numOfQuestions).ToList();
var round3Questions = Entities.Questions.Where(q => q.Round == 3)
                          .OrderBy(r => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(numOfQuestions).ToList();

/* ==== BEGIN TEST ==== */
foreach (var q in round1Questions)
{
   if ((q.Round != 3 && q.Answers.Count != 4) || (q.Round == 3 && q.Answers.Count != 1))
      throw new InvalidDataException("This question has less answers than it should");
}
/* ==== END TEST ==== */

/* ==== BEGIN TEST ==== */
foreach (var q in round2Questions)
{
   if ((q.Round != 3 && q.Answers.Count != 4) || (q.Round == 3 && q.Answers.Count != 1))
      throw new InvalidDataException("This question has less answers than it should");
}
/* ==== END TEST ==== */

/* ==== BEGIN TEST ==== */
foreach (var q in round3Questions)
{
   if ((q.Round != 3 && q.Answers.Count != 4) || (q.Round == 3 && q.Answers.Count != 1))
      throw new InvalidDataException("This question has less answers than it should");
}
/* ==== END TEST ==== */
```

As you can see I run a test to verify the data. **The code above works perfectly: no exception is thrown.**

**However**, if I use early loading of the entity "Answers" and "GameResults" (which is not needed by the test but it's used elsewhere), the test fails for some rows. Why is that?
Here is the "broken" code:

```
var round1Questions = Entities.Questions.Include("Answers").Include("GamesResults")
                          .Where(q => q.Round == 1).OrderBy(r => Guid.NewGuid())
                          .Take(numOfQuestions).ToList();
var round2Questions = Entities.Questions.Include("Answers").Include("GamesResults")
                          .Where(q => q.Round == 2).OrderBy(r => Guid.NewGuid())
                          .Take(numOfQuestions).ToList();
var round3Questions = Entities.Questions.Include("Answers").Include("GamesResults")
                          .Where(q => q.Round == 3).OrderBy(r => Guid.NewGuid())
                          .Take(numOfQuestions).ToList();

/* Omitted the test code because it's the same as above */
```

PS: it always fails at the first test at some rows but not all. And the Data Model is automatically generated by Visual Studio, using the designer.

**UPDATE**

1. I run the exact same test on each collection (Round 1 and 2 should
   have 4 answers. Round 3 should have 1 answer.)
2. If I don't include
   the "GamesResults" entity when calling the "Include" method,
   everything works.
3. **So, the problem only occurs when I include both, "GamesResults" and "Answers".**

Comment: You use the same test `if ((q.Round != 3 ...` in each of your tests, but it looks like they should be 1, 2, or 3 depending on which foreach you're in... To put it another way, you're iterating through `round1Questions`, but testing is `q.Round != 3` everywhere. Not sure if that's your problem, but it looks like a problem.

Comment: No, that's not a problem because "round1Questions" only contains questions with property Round = 1 so that part of the condition would be ignored. And same for the other two collections

Comment: why do you separate them, if you run the same if condition on all collections?? you could just take away either half the if-conditions respectively or iterate only a single collection...

Comment: So, during the foreach on `round3Questions`, you expect `q.Round` to *not* be 3?

Comment: @Vogel612: I separate them because I want exactly 200 random questions for round 1, exactly 200 random questions for round 2 and so for Round 3.

Comment: @Steve: During the foreach on "round3Questions", I expect q.Round to BE 3. But that's not the problem: the problem is on the first foreach. Please also read my updates.

Comment: @Vogel612: nothing changes using "!=" operator. I update the code so other won't get confused.

Comment: What happens, when you don't include the Answers?

Comment: If I don't include answers, the code works (because it load answers using lazy loading). As you can see, the first code I posted works because it doesn't include anything. But as you might already know, lazy loading is always slower than early loading.

Comment: sorry, should've been clearer. What if you only include GamesResults? or are they depending on the answers?

Comment: @Vogel612 I tried including only "GamesResults" and it works. So it occurs ONLY when I include both, "GamesResults" and "Answers".